# Exportar datos sql server a excel C# window form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy exportando datos de una base de datos en Sql Server a un Excel. Lo estoy realizando en C# de tipo Windows Forms.

Si me exporta la información, pero las columnas de mi tabla no las genera y ademas algunos campos le pone como verdadero como se muestra en esta la imagen:

> Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

señalando esta linea de codigo:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
```

Este es el código:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        SqlConnection cnn;
        string connectionstring = null;
        string sql = null;
      string data = null;

        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        connectionstring = "server=192.168.105.150\\sql2012;    database=Credito;         user id=sa;                   password=DBServ@14;";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        cnn.Open();


        sql = "SELECT top 1 * FROM credito..cuotacredito"; 

        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(ds);

        DataTable miTabla = ds.Tables[0];


        for (i = 1; i < miTabla.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

            // Recorrer las columnas de la tabla:
            for (j = 1; j < miTabla.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                //xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j].Value = miTabla.Rows[j][i].ToString();
            }

        }







        /*
   for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
       {

           data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
           data1 = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ToString();
           xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data+data1;

       }

   } */


        xlApp.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: @RandallSandoval parece que imgur está en mantenimiento...

Comment: @RandallSandoval si amigo estan en mantenimiento

Comment: @Pierro solo haces el recorrido a las filas `ds.Tables[0].Rows`, en ningún momento a las columnas de tu tabla `ds.Tables[0].Columns`.

Comment: @Davlio muchas gracias:

yo le agregado en mi for pero ahora solo me muestra mi columnas y ninguna fila.

  for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
                   
                }
            }

Comment: @Pierro puedes responder entonces tu misma pregunta :) [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Pierro, comenta esa línea (la que te da error): `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();` y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave lo comente y me señalo error el siguiente codigo que esta debajo:

 xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Rows[j][i].ToString();

Comment: @Pierro, cambia el valor "0" a "1"; así: `i = 1` y `j = 1`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave si salio el excel pero en blanco todo

Comment: @Pierro agrega así: `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j].Value = miTabla.Rows[j][i].ToString();`

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave me sale en blanco

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que está fallando y no se mostraba las filas y códigos es porque no se estaba mostrando y tambien agregando este código:

```
for (int i = 1; i < miTabla.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{    
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = miTabla.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
}

for (int j = 0; j < miTabla.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < miTabla.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = miTabla.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();       
    }
}

xlApp.Visible = true;


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cnn;
    string connectionstring = null;
    string sql = null;
    string data = null;

    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    connectionstring = "server=192.168.105.150\\sql2012;    database=Credito;         user id=sa;                   password=DBServ@14;";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    cnn.Open();   

    sql = "SELECT top 1 * FROM credito..cuotacredito"; 

    SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dscmd.Fill(ds);

    DataTable miTabla = ds.Tables[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < miTabla.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = miTabla.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < miTabla.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < miTabla.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = miTabla.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
        }
    }

    xlApp.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Hola Pierro. Excelente que contribuyas tu solución. Pero para que sea una respuesta de calidad que pueda ser de utilidad a otros, sería apropiado que el código vaya acompañado de una explicación clara de lo que era el problema y de dónde lo solucionastes en el código.

Comment: Apoyo completamente el comentario de @sstan y además complementaría con que edites la respuesta y pongas adecuadamente las secciones de código, veo ahí un par que están como que fuera de contexto, editaría la pregunta para poder arreglarlo pero no estoy seguro si eso entorpecería lo que deseas transimitir

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda que en 48 horas podrás marcar tu respuesta como válida, esto con el fin de ir alimentando una adecuada base de preguntas y respestas :D

Comment: @Flxtr disculpe es que soy nuevo la verdad en c#.
y no tengo mucho conocimiento en dar como explicacion:

Comment: @Flxtr 
  Disculpen yo le hice un query normal como ven la respuesta pero si decearia en ves que esa query que sea un procedure como podria realizar  me podrian ayudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Después de esta línea:

```
dscmd.Fill(ds);
```

Crea una variable de tipo `Datatable` de esta manera:

```
// Esta es la tabla que exportarás a Excel.
DataTable miTabla = ds.Tables[0];
```

Y modifica tu código de una manera similar a este pseudo-código:

```
// Recorrer las filas de la tabla.
for (int filas = 1; filas < miTabla.Rows.Count; filas++) {
    
    // Recorrer las columnas de la tabla:
    for (int cols = 1; cols < miTabla.Columns.Count; cols++) {

        // En la celda de la hoja de Excel coloco el valor de esa celda del DataTable:
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[filas, cols].Value = miTabla.Rows[cols][filas].ToString();
    }    
}
```

> NOTA: En Excel, no existe el índice en 0, por ello, la primera
> posición es 1.
>
> [Fuente](https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c)

Comment: si le puesto como tu indicaste lo modifique pero me sale un error extraño en el codigo: 
Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

for (i = 0; i < miTabla.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

                // Recorrer las columnas de la tabla:
                for (j = 0; j < miTabla.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = miTabla.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                }
            }

Comment: @Pierro, por favor edita tu pregunta al darle click a este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52237/edit). Agrega también allí la descripción del error.

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta